# Not able to submit channel update while changing consensus type on Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to migrate kafka to raft on Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.3, when submitting peer channel update i'm getting following error. I'm using BYFN to do so.

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST – error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value] /Channel/Orderer/ConsensusType not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

I've followed this doc https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/kafka_raft_migration.html and first I'm only trying to Change state from NORMAL to MAINTENANCE in mychannel.

I've used orderer admin and OrdererMSP to submit peer channel update.

On 1.4.2 all works but same on 1.4.3 fails

Comment: You can take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662562/when-i-try-to-create-a-channel-using-hyperledger-fabric-the-request-fails