# How to create a channel block in Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to create a channel block but I get the error below. I am using an [article](https://medium.com/@kctheservant/demo-of-multi-channel-network-in-hyperledger-fabric-640f7158e2d3) in medium. Has anyone any ideas about this?

> ~/fabric/fabric-samples/multi-channel-network$ docker exec -e
>   "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e
>   "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
>   -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp"
>   -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051" -it cli bash root@6379d63c48b5:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#
>   export
>   ORDERER_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
>   root@6379d63c48b5:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#
>   peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c channelall -f
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts/channelall.tx
>   --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA 2019-09-24 10:46:28.542 UTC [main] InitCmd -> WARN 001 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable 2019-09-24 10:46:28.546 UTC
>   [main] SetOrdererEnv -> WARN 002 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer
>   supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable
>   2019-09-24 10:46:28.550 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003
>   Endorser and orderer connections initialized Error: got unexpected
>   status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction
>   for new channel 'channelall', could not succesfully apply update to
>   template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating
>   DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied:
>   implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but
>   this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

Comment: You can take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662562/when-i-try-to-create-a-channel-using-hyperledger-fabric-the-request-fails

Comment: The sooner this forums are blockchain based the better, then we can remove centralised control and see who does what.

Comment: @TrevorOakley you're right, brother.

Answer (score 0):

How to create a channel block in hyperledger fabric. I'm writing the step from begining from where you generate your crypto materials, assuming that you're running first-network. which means you're in

```
cd fabric-samples/first-network
```

First, generate crypto materials

1. `../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml`

Export this path i,e. run this command

2. `export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD`

Create a genesis block

3. `../bin/configtxgen -profile SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block`

Export channel name

4. `export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel`

Create channel , this will create channel.tx

5. `../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME`

Comment: I am asking about multi-channels which is not addressed by your answer. Your answer is the single channel case which is entirely different.

Comment: to create multi-channels just start this step again and simply change the name of channel.tx to < anything you want > .

Comment: I had a specific error which I posted. I can copy paste from the docs about channel creation.