# config update for existing channel did not pass initial checks

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

when I try to build my network, I just copy the byfn sample files, but it doesn't work for me. I even don't change a word. So how can I fix it?
Config update for existing channel did not pass initial checks:

> implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

Comment: Can you specify the versions of Fabric, the Samples and client binaries you are using. (Sometimes you see this error with mis-matched versions.)

Comment: I have the same problem, I am on HL Fabric 1.4.4 ( 1.4.4 /1.4.4 / 0.4.18 )

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably due to the wrong certificates of identities used while submitting the request. Eg: while creating channel. Follow this SO post    [When I try to create a channel using Hyperledger Fabric, the request fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662562/when-i-try-to-create-a-channel-using-hyperledger-fabric-the-request-fails/57662645#57662645)

For a quick workaround you can restart the network by creating new set of crypto material if you're not sure about which exact identity is creating the problem. Don't forget to do a `docker network prune` and `docker volume prune` before restarting.