# Hyperledger fabric 2.0-Error in chaincode commit step(ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to install chaincode (Using a new chaincode life cycle) in hyper ledger fabric 2.0.

Fabric image versions: 2.1.0

In my network I have

1. Two organization (two peers each)
2. 3 Orders (Raft as order service)

During the commit chaincode step, i m getting the following error

```
2021-08-04 06:36:29.803 UTC [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 001 txid [ebca06fc317ef078d896182e7814f3d9e847266b2fa4a80ae443e17a9ad976da] committed with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE) at peer1.base.left:8003
2021-08-04 06:36:29.816 UTC [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 002 txid [ebca06fc317ef078d896182e7814f3d9e847266b2fa4a80ae443e17a9ad976da] committed with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE) at peer1.base.right:8004
Error: transaction invalidated with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE)
```

While inspecting the peer logs i can see the following error

```
2021-08-04 06:36:29.755 UTC [committer.txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 004 Dispatch for transaction txId = ebca06fc317ef078d896182e7814f3d9e847266b2fa4a80ae443e17a9ad976da returned error: validation of endorsement policy for chaincode _lifecycle in tx 8:0 failed: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 2 of the 'Endorsement' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

Not sure why this is happening

**UPDATE configtx.yaml file**

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer1.base.order:8000

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: LeftOrgMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: LeftOrgMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/base.left/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('LeftOrgMSP.admin', 'LeftOrgMSP.peer', 'LeftOrgMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('LeftOrgMSP.admin', 'LeftOrgMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('LeftOrgMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('LeftOrgMSP.peer')"

    - &Org2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: RightOrgMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: RightOrgMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/base.right/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('RightOrgMSP.admin', 'RightOrgMSP.peer', 'RightOrgMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('RightOrgMSP.admin', 'RightOrgMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('RightOrgMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('RightOrgMSP.peer')"

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
        # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
        # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
        # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
        # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    # Addresses used to be the list of orderer addresses that clients and peers
    # could connect to.  However, this does not allow clients to associate orderer
    # addresses and orderer organizations which can be useful for things such
    # as TLS validation.  The preferred way to specify orderer addresses is now
    # to include the OrdererEndpoints item in your org definition
    Addresses:
         - orderer1.base.order:8000
         - orderer2.base.order:8000
         - orderer3.base.order:8000
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
                - Host: orderer1.base.order
                  Port: 8000
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer2.base.order
                  Port: 8000
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer2.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer2.base.order/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer3.base.order
                  Port: 8000
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer3.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer3.base.order/tls/server.crt

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Endorsement"
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    MainChannel:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities: *ApplicationCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            BaseConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    AnyOrgsChannel:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Consortium: BaseConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect endorsement from a peer from both Orgs in order to meet the LifeCycle endorsement policy. This error could be because you are not targeting either peer, or because your orgs have not approved the same chaincode definition as the one you are trying to commit

Answer (score 0):

In your config.tx file you have mentioned **LifecycleEndorsement**  as **MAJORITY Endorsement** that means your transaction should be endorse by a peer from both organizations.

to achive this make sure

1. your chaincode is approved by both the organizations
2. while running commit command pass the peer connection parameters (--peerAddresses $CORE_PEER_ADDRESS --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE) for any peer from both organizations.