# Fabric channel update error: this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

## 1. Error

To update my channel config (called `identitych`), I fetched, translated, modified, and re-encoded channel config file by following the guide in [the official document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/config_update.html#editing-a-config).

At the last step, I tried to submit my channel config update with the following command.

```sh
peer channel update -f config_update_in_envelope.pb -c identitych -o orderer1.common.bpl:7050 --tls --cafile /orderers/admin-ca/msp/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem
```

But, I failed with the following error.

```
2021-09-02 12:52:53.987 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'identitych': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/ConsensusType not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

Error message from the logs recorded by `orderer1.common.bpl` is like below. I could not find any relevant error messages except this message.

```sh
2021-09-02 12:52:53.993 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 54f6 [channel: identitych] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 10.0.1.104:54556 because of error: error applying config update to existing channel 'identitych': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/ConsensusType not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
2021-09-02 12:52:53.993 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 54f7 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=10.0.1.104:54556 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=2.028426ms
```

## 2. My setting

To use `peer update` command, I used a cli docker container, which had been created by the following command:

```
docker container run -it --rm --name cli \
--log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=1g --log-opt max-file=1 \
-e GOPATH=/opt/gopath \
-e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock \
-e FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO \
-e CORE_PEER_ID=cli \
-e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer3.identity.common.bpl:7051 \
-e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=BPLMSP \
-e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/peers/admin-org/msp \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/peers/peer3.identity.common.bpl/tls/keystore/key.pem \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/peers/peer3.identity.common.bpl/tls/signcerts/cert.pem \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/peers/peer3.identity.common.bpl/tls/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem \
-w="/peers" \
-v /var/run/:/host/var/run/ \
-v "$(pwd)"/peers:/peers \
-v "$(pwd)"/channel-artifacts:/channel-artifacts \
-v "$(pwd)"/chaincodes:/chaincodes \
-v "$(pwd)"/orderers:/orderers \
-v "$(pwd)"/scripts:/scripts \
--network $NETWORK \
hyperledger/fabric-tools:$VERSION /bin/bash
```

As you can see in the above script, this cli container starts with necessary environment variable settings(such as `CORE_PEER_TLS_...`) to connect the target peer. Also, `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` pointed the admin user's `msp` directory.

By following the answer of the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57662645/1331366) in stackoverflow, I checked my admin user's cert is correct.

At the root location of my admin user's `msp` directory, `config.yaml` had been placed and its content is like below:

```
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: "cacerts/cacert.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "client"
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: "cacerts/cacert.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "admin"
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: "cacerts/cacert.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "peer"
  OrdererOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: "cacerts/cacert.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "orderer"
```

So, its OU setting looks correct.

Then, I checked my admin user's `signcerts/cert.pem` using `openssl` command.

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
...
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C=KR, ST=Daejeon, O=bigpicturelabs, CN=ca.peer.common.bpl
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep  2 12:47:00 2021 GMT
            Not After : Sep  4 04:51:00 2035 GMT
        Subject: C=KR, ST=Daejeon, O=bigpicturelabs, OU=admin, CN=bpl-peer-admin
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub: 
...
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
...
            1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
                {"attrs":{"hf.Affiliation":"","hf.EnrollmentID":"bpl-peer-admin","hf.Type":"admin"}}
...
```

From `Subject` section, I could confirm that its `OU` value had been set correctly as `admin` and `CN` also had been set correctly. So far, everything looks like good.

Then, I validated my admin user's `cert` against the root certificate extracted from the channel config. The way to do it was introduced at the above question in stackoverflow. And, again, I got the correct answer.

```sh
> openssl verify -CAfile root.pem ./admin-org/msp/signcerts/cert.pem 
./admin-org/msp/signcerts/cert.pem: OK
```

Then, finally, I checked the `configtx.yaml` content.

```yaml
Organizations:
  - &BPLOrdererOrg
    Name: BPLOrdererMSP
    ID: BPLOrdererMSP
    MSPDir: ./orderers/admin-ca/msp

    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('BPLOrdererMSP.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('BPLOrdererMSP.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('BPLOrdererMSP.admin')"

    OrdererEndpoints:
      - orderer0.common.bpl:7050

  - &BPLOrg
    Name: BPLMSP
    ID: BPLMSP
    MSPDir: ./peers/admin-ca/msp

    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('BPLMSP.admin', 'BPLMSP.peer', 'BPLMSP.client')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('BPLMSP.admin', 'BPLMSP.client')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('BPLMSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('BPLMSP.peer')"

    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: peer0.identity.common.bpl
        Port: 7051

Capabilities:
  Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    V2_0: true

  Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V2_0: true

  Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:

  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    LifecycleEndorsement:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Endorsement:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

  Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: etcdraft

  EtcdRaft:
    Consenters:
      - Host: orderer0.common.bpl
        Port: 7050
        ClientTLSCert: ./orderers/orderer0.common.bpl/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
        ServerTLSCert: ./orderers/orderer0.common.bpl/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - Host: orderer1.common.bpl
        Port: 7050
        ClientTLSCert: ./orderers/orderer1.common.bpl/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
        ServerTLSCert: ./orderers/orderer1.common.bpl/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - Host: orderer2.common.bpl
        Port: 7050
        ClientTLSCert: ./orderers/orderer2.common.bpl/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
        ServerTLSCert: ./orderers/orderer2.common.bpl/tls/signcerts/cert.pem

  BatchTimeout: 0.5s

  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 100
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

  Organizations:

  Policies:
...
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
...

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
  Policies:
...
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

  Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities
...
```

Again, I could not find any problem from my configuration file.

## 3. Question

Is there any point that I'm missing? Where should I investigate to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by working with orderer's admin, not peer organization's admin. I'm not sure why, but it works.

Comment: Hi I am also getting the same error, could you explain how you solved it. ..where did you use orderers admin ?

Comment: Byron1st, how did you solve?